# How to use a loop to check multiple conditions on multiple columns to filter a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have a list containing names of the columns of a dataframe.

```
x = ['USPR', 'ESA', 'OSFI', 'APRA']
```

The values for these columns are either 'Yes' or 'No'.

I want to filter out rows that'd have any of the columns having 'Yes'. I want to use maybe a for loop to iterate through the list because the list is created from user input. So instead of having a static check like below:

```
df = df[(df['USPR'] == 'Yes') | (df['ESA'] == 'Yes') | (df['OSFI'] == 'Yes') | (df['APRA'] == 'Yes')]
```

I'm wondering how to make this dynamic using a loop, i.e. number of the conditions checked would be equal to the length of `x`. Or any other suggestion to achieve the outcome would also be appreciated.

Much thanks.

For the below sample dataframe:

[image]

I'm supposed to get the filtered dataframe as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to remove all the rows where all values are "no".

original df:

| USPR | ESA | OFI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| yes | no | yes |
| no | yes | yes |
| no | no | no |

```
df = df[(df != "no").any(axis=1)]
```

Output:

| USPR | ESA | OFI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| yes | no | yes |
| no | yes | yes |

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
for i in x:
    print(f"checking.. {i}")
    if len(df[df[i] == 'yes']) > 0:
        print(f"true for {i}")
    else:
        print(f"false for {i}")
```

The output:

```
checking.. USPR
true for USPR
checking.. ESA
true for ESA
checking.. OSFI
false for OSFI
```

For remove the column with no

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    print(f"checking.. {x[i]}")
    if len(df[df[x[i]] == 'yes']) > 0:
        continue
    else:
        df.drop(x[i], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Instead of printing, how to get the filtered and final dataframe after all the checks are done?

Comment: I put some lines in the answer, did you try it?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get the desired result. The purpose is to filter out rows where either of the columns in list x would have 'Yes'. The code didn't exclude a row for which all columns had 'No'.

Comment: Please see the pics in original question above.

Comment: I just reply with new answer. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand what you want...
Anyway i will leave my suggestion

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['USPR', 'ESA', 'OSFI', 'APRA'], columns=['country'])
df
```

#### Output

|  | country |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | USPR |
| 1 | ESA |
| 2 | OSFI |
| 3 | APRA |

#### Create a function to store how many Ifs you want...

```
def foo(x):
    if x == 'USPR':
        return 'Yes'
    elif x == 'ESA':
        return 'Yes'
    elif x == 'OSFI':
        return 'Yes'
    elif x == 'APRA':
        return 'Yes'
df['new_col'] = df.country.apply(foo)
```

##### Output

|  | country | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USPR | Yes |
| 1 | ESA | Yes |
| 2 | OSFI | Yes |
| 3 | APRA | Yes |